# Insert adding items to wrong column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

Below is an insert statement that is inputting the first value `(acctNum)` into the second column `(itemCode)` and vice versa:

```
string addUpcCode = "INSERT INTO compare1 (acct, itemcode)"
                    + "VALUES ('"+acctNum+"', '"+itemCode+"')";
```

This is not how I want it to work, as I want the first value to go in the first column and the second in the second column. How can I go about this?

Side note: This is a rough draft until I learn more about parameterization. I won't be releasing this code until I learn and implement it.

Comment: This SQL **will** keep the sequence intact - most possibly you just got your variables mixed up.

Comment: I had them mixed up in the class args. Thanks! Didn't think to look there.

Comment: By the way, if you put your comment in the form of an answer, I'd mark it considering you were the first to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given SQL snipplet will do what you want - especially the sequence of columns will be preserved.

I suspect you might have switched your variables, leading to the same phenomen but out of  an other reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SQL Parameters which also avoids creating a SQL injection problem:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO compare1 (acct, itemcode) VALUES (@AcctNum, @ItemCode)", connection))
{
    // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("AcctNum", acctNum));
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ItemCode", itemCode));
```

Comment: I'm aware, and made my awareness apparent at the bottom of the post. A buddy of mine has been consistently on me about it. Thank you for the heads up and concern.

Comment: -1 ... while this is true, it has absolutely zero relevance for the OQ

Answer (score 0):

As you're using C# the string.format function is perfect for this kind of thing

```
    string.format("INSERT INTO compare1(acct, itemCode) Values('{0}','{1}'", acctNum, itemCode);
```

or

```
    string.format("INSERT INTO compare1 SELECT '{0}','{1}' ", acctNum, itemCode);
```

But yeah, you probably have them mixed up somewhere else, the order will be kept. Oh and if acctNum is an integer, you won't need the quotation marks around {0}

Edit:
Oh and yeah, definitely look into parameters next

Answer (score 0):

Use parametrized queries to prevent SQL injection and you can solve this matter

```
 command.Parameters.Add("AcctNum", acctNum);
```